# Finite group with cyclic Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are cyclic of order $p^2$. I know the number of cyclic subgroups of order $p^2$ is equal to the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups. I would like to know what is the number of cyclic subgroups of order $p$?

Comment: Every subgroup of order $p$ is contained in a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Every cyclic group of order $p^2$ contains exactly one subgroup of order $p$. The question is whether two Sylow $p$-subgroups have trivial intersection, or nontrivial.

Comment: How much of the theory of these groups do you know? Are you aware that the $p$-Sylow, where $p$ is the largest prime divisor, is normal?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: If a Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal, then the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is $1$. Then the number of cyclic subgroups of order $p$ in the $G$ is $1$.

Comment: So we now know that it is at least the case when $p$ is the largest prime divisor. Now consider the case where $|G|$ has only two prime divisors. Can it happen that the $q$-Sylows (where $q$ is the other prime divisor) intersects non-trivially?

Comment: By "being the case" I mean that the number of subgroups of order $p$ is the same as the number of order $p^2$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thanks. In other words, the number of cyclic subgroups of order $p$ is equal to the number of Sylow subgroups. Is it true?

Comment: Well, we have concluded that it is the case for the largest prime dividing the order of the group. I am not sure if it also holds for the other primes.

Comment: No it is not always true that the number of subgroups of order $p$ (all subgroups of order $p$ are cyclic) is equal to the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups because, as Daniel Fisher said earlier, two of the Sylow $p$-subgroups might intersect in a subgroup of order $p$. So the number is something between 1 and the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Comment: I think you can show that if the Sylow $p$-subgroups are cyclic of order $p^n$, then for $0 \leq k \leq n$, the number of subgroups of order $p^k$ is $\equiv 1 \mod{p^{n-k+1}}$. So in your question, the number of subgroups of order $p$ is $\equiv 1 \mod{p^2}$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: The number of subgroups of order $p$ in this special situation is $[G:N_{G}(Q)],$ where $Q$ is any subgroup of order $p$ of $G.$ Notice that if $P$ is a subgroup of order $p^{2}$ containing $Q,$ then $N_{G}(P)] \leq N_{G}(Q),$ and that $P \cap P^{g} = 1$ for all $g \in G \backslash N_{G}(Q).$